# how to check for the elapsed time of a timer in c#

Tags: c#, timer

My code is below:

```
    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time--;
        Timelbl.Text = "Time: " + time + " seconds";

        if (time == 0)
        {
            Timer.Stop();
            Timelbl.Text = "Time: " + 0 + " seconds";
        }
    }
```

I want to know how I can check how long it has been since the timer has started. For example if the variable time was 30,after 20 seconds, I want to know that the timer started 20 seconds ago, but the problem is that the value of the variable time changes all the time so how will I go about doing this in c#?

Comment: A `Timer` is for triggering events using a specified interval. A `Stopwatch` measures time. If you need to measure time, use a `Stopwatch`. If you need to do x event every y seconds, use a `Timer`. Or better yet, write a class that uses a timer to track time and exposes an event to fire every so often, like a `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 4):

So this basically boils down to `Timer` vs. `Stopwatch`.

A `Timer` per the docs: Generates an event after a set interval, with an option to generate recurring events.

A `Stopwatch` per the docs: Provides a set of methods and properties that you can use to accurately measure elapsed time.

You can set up a `Stopwatch` to be a property of your `Form` and then update the UI in your `Timer` event to update the UI and show the elapsed time by doing something like:

```
Timelbl.Text = "Time: " + (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000).ToString() + " seconds";
```

Assuming `sw` is of type `Stopwatch`.

Let me know if you need specific help setting up a `Stopwatch` on your form / if you hit snags getting that set up.